Why azure function is not triggered when custom web API skill is invoked in the skillset pipeline to extract page number?
I'm following this SO post to extract page-number from a pure text-based pdf. I've created a page_number field in my index.
I've also created a custom web API skill using azure functions and mapped the output of the skill enrichment using OuputFieldMappings array in my indexer definition. Down below in the azure function definition, I have assumed the request data would look like this as it is mentioned in the said SO post. Is this assumption correct? How do developers test their skillset enrichment steps?
{
    "data": "BASE64 ENCODED STRING OF A JPEG IMAGE",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 300,
    "originalWidth": 5000,  
    "originalHeight": 3000,
    "rotationFromOriginal": 90,
    "contentOffset": 500,
    "pageNumber": 2
  }

After running the indexer, I monitor logs via log streaming in my azure function app resource created for deployment and no info logs are generated. I suspect that my custom web api skill is not getting invoked when the skillset runs. And hence this is why page_number field is always null when I perform a vector search query on my search index. I've listed the definitions of my skillset, azure function and indexer, Can anyone please guide on what I'm missing? TIA
Skillset definition
{
  "@odata.context": "https://ai-studio-search-test.search.windows.net/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC9745F955DC29\"",
  "name": "test-skillset",
  "description": "Skillset to chunk documents and generating embeddings",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
      "name": "#1",
      "description": "Split skill to chunk documents",
      "context": "/document",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "textSplitMode": "pages",
      "maximumPageLength": 2000,
      "pageOverlapLength": 500,
      "maximumPagesToTake": 0,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/content"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "textItems",
          "targetName": "pages"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill",
      "name": "#2",
      "description": "Skill to generate embeddings via Azure OpenAI",
      "context": "/document/pages/*",
      "resourceUri": "https://crowemind-non-prd-us-east-2.openai.azure.com",
      "apiKey": "<redacted>",
      "deploymentId": "text-embedding-ada-002",
      "dimensions": 1536,
      "modelName": "text-embedding-ada-002",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/pages/*"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "embedding",
          "targetName": "vector"
        }
      ],
      "authIdentity": null
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
      "name": "#3",
      "description": "",
      "context": "/document/normalized_images/*",
      "uri": "https://azure-searchskill-apis.azurewebsites.net/api/pageno_skillapi_anonymous",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "timeout": "PT30S",
      "batchSize": 1,
      "degreeOfParallelism": 1,
      "authResourceId": null,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "normalized_images",
          "source": "/document/normalized_images/*"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "page_number",
          "targetName": "page_number"
        }
      ],
      "httpHeaders": {},
      "authIdentity": null
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": null,
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": {
    "selectors": [
      {
        "targetIndexName": "test-index-secondary",
        "parentKeyFieldName": "parent_id",
        "sourceContext": "/document",
        "mappings": [
          {
            "name": "chunk",
            "source": "/document/pages/*",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          },
          {
            "name": "text_vector",
            "source": "/document/pages/*/vector",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          },
          {
            "name": "title",
            "source": "/document/metadata_storage_name",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          },
          {
            "name": "page_number",
            "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/page_number",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {
      "projectionMode": "skipIndexingParentDocuments"
    }
  },
  "encryptionKey": null
}

Azure Function Deployed
@app.route(route="pageno_skillapi_anonymous", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def pageno_skillapi_anonymous(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    payload = req.get_json()
    if payload:
        logging.info("request body received from /document/normalized_images/* context")
        logging.info(f"payload: ${payload}")

        if "pageNumber" in payload:
            page_number = payload
            return func.HttpResponse(str(payload["pageNumber"]), status_code=200)
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse("No pageNumber parameter in /document/normalized_images/* context", status_code=200)

    else:
        logging.info("request body is empty")
        return func.HttpResponse("request body is empty", status_code=200)


Indexer Definition
{
  "@odata.context": "https://ai-studio-search-test.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC976AFC2C0D01\"",
  "name": "test-indexer",
  "description": "Indexer to index documents and generate embeddings",
  "dataSourceName": "test-blob",
  "skillsetName": "test-skillset",
  "targetIndexName": "test-index",
  "disabled": false,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": null,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": null,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "parsingMode": "default",
      "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImagePerPage"
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_name",
      "targetFieldName": "title",
      "mappingFunction": null
    }
  ],
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/page_number",
      "targetFieldName": "page_number"
    }
  ],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}

I have tried changing the context of custom the field which did not do anything.

I don't understand why my post is getting downvoted...

what is the output for logging.info(f"payload: ${payload}"). and the targetIndexName in index projection in skillset definition should be the secondary index and not your primary index also the context you are using is /document/pages/* and referring to /document/normalized_images/*/page_number so try with the secondary index with required fields .

I do not see any logs in the azure function app resource, thats why I raised the post. I don't even know if the function actually gets triggered in the skill enrichment pipeline. Thanks for pointing out the secondary index, I have create a secondary index and changed the context to /document in the index projections. But still, page_number field is still null . I have edited the index projection with new changes, does it look right now?

does the OutputFieldMappings look correct for the mapping the page_number?

According to this documentation when you set the imageAction you will get the array of images in the /document/normalized_images/* context
so, you can not the do output field mappings in the primary index, if you do mappings you need to do it to the field of type collection of the result datatype like below.

To get the data separately, you need to create secondary index and do projections on it.
You no need to pass page_number to you custom web api skill it is already configured when you give imageAction as generateNormalizedImages.
So, you can use ocr skillset to extract text from page and do projection with page number.
Below is the skillset definition.
{
  "@odata.context": "https://jgsai.search.windows.net/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC9A7C02836ACA\"",
  "name": "skillset1719835991688",
  "description": "",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Vision.OcrSkill",
      "name": "#1",
      "description": null,
      "context": "/document/normalized_images/*",
      "textExtractionAlgorithm": null,
      "lineEnding": "Space",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "detectOrientation": true,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "image",
          "source": "/document/normalized_images/*"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "targetName": "text"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.DefaultCognitiveServices",
    "description": null
  },
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": {
    "selectors": [
      {
        "targetIndexName": "test-index",
        "parentKeyFieldName": "parent_id",
        "sourceContext": "/document/normalized_images/*",
        "mappings": [
          {
            "name": "page_number",
            "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/pageNumber",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          },
          {
            "name": "page_content",
            "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/text",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {
      "projectionMode": "skipIndexingParentDocuments"
    }
  },
  "encryptionKey": null
}

Indexer definition
{
  "@odata.context": "https://jgsai.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC9A7C1434746D\"",
  "name": "azureblob-indexer",
  "description": "",
  "dataSourceName": "ds",
  "skillsetName": "skillset1719835991688",
  "targetIndexName": "azureblob-index",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": 0,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "parsingMode": "default",
      "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImages"
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode",
        "parameters": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputFieldMappings": [],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}

and target index definition.
{
  "@odata.context": "https://jgsai.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC9A73656E2423\"",
  "name": "test-index",
  "defaultScoringProfile": null,
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": true,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "keyword",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "parent_id",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "page_number",
      "type": "Edm.Int64",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "page_content",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    }
  ],
  "scoringProfiles": [],
  "corsOptions": null,
  "suggesters": [],
  "analyzers": [],
  "normalizers": [],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "tokenFilters": [],
  "charFilters": [],
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "similarity": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity",
    "k1": null,
    "b": null
  },
  "semantic": null,
  "vectorSearch": null
}

Output:

If you want to customize your data with custom web api then
you use below function code.
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import json
import base64

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger1")
def http_trigger1(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    values = req.get_json()['values']
    res=[]
    content = base64.b64decode(i['data']['normalized_images']['data']) #do whatever you want with this image.
    for i in values:
        tmp = i
        tmp['data'] = {
            "page_number": i['data']['normalized_images']['pageNumber']
        }
        res.append(tmp)

    return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps({"values":res}),mimetype="application/json")


For more information combining normalized images and custom web api refer this.

@JayshakarGS I tried this and created a new example, thank you that makes sense. But I have two questions:

How do I map the skillset outputs to the primary index?  In the new example I created after following your instruction, the primary index has 0 documents.



Since the secondary index is populated with documents, I tried query searching in there but I have seem to found that the retrieved search results contain only content from images in the pdf and page number of the image in the pdf. In short, the pure text based content does now show up in results. How do I fix this?


First, to populate to primary index. you need a field which is of collection. If you want to populate pagenumber then you need a field in primary index of type collection(int.64), if it is content then collection(string).

In you secondary index you are mapping the direct data. to get content you add text extraction skill set which ocr and map the output of ocr skillset to secondary index.

actually that is image data in base64 encode so use ocr to extract text and map /document/normalized_images/*/pageNumber directly to secondary index no need of custom web api.

@JayShankarGS but how do I map the fields in the primary index? Do I have to use outputFieldMappings in the indexer for this?

also are you saying in order to extract content/text I would have to use EntityRecognitionSkill? but OCR should be taking care of the text and page number both right? since generateNormalizedImages converts each page into images?

I understand that custom skillset is not needed

yes you need to use outputFieldMappings  to populate results in primary index.
OCR gives you the output text and layout please refer MS docs and pageNumber you will get by default in the context /document/normalized_images/*. all you have to do is index projection with ocr skillset.

Look my solution properly i have given the definitions.

I have tried your solution, the page number and text are getting retrieved however the page numbers refer to the page number where image is located in the pdf and the text only contains content from the corresponding image. This is NOT the complete solution. I want the non-image text also get indexed and the solution you have proposed indexes only the images in the documents.

It will be in your primary index /document/content, it contains whole pdf data in string format and not associated with any page number. Also, you really need to check about azure ai search concepts in MS docs. In non-image content you can do chunking to split it but not according to page number. only way is using imageAction option.
